# What's this linguistic, phonetic or phonologic phenomenon called?

Tags: american-english, british-english, spoken-english, phonetics, phonology

> I was enjoying the relaxing vibes that the hotel provided.

When Americans say the above sentence, do they sometimes say "vibes that" as "vibesat"?

Does it also happen in other English dialects?

What's the linguistic phenomenon called? Is it a
phonetical or phonological one?

It might belong to the same phenomenon that "I like him/them" is spoken as "I likeum"

Comment: Probably some Americans do. It might be called 'mumbling' or 'not speaking clearly'. This is not a sensible question for this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a sensible question for this site.

Comment: sensible if you.recognize that English language has not only four dialects

Comment: People in all Anglophone countries (and, no doubt, speakers of other languages) sometimes elide words unless they are speaking slowly and carefully.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I disagree. It is a relevant question.

Answer (score 1):

> In linguistics, connected speech or connected discourse is a
> continuous sequence of sounds forming utterances or conversations in
> spoken language. Analysis of connected speech shows sound changes
> affecting linguistic units traditionally described as phrases, words,
> lexemes, morphemes, syllables, phonemes or phones.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_speech#:%7E:text=In%20linguistics%2C%20connected%20speech%20or,%2C%20syllables%2C%20phonemes%20or%20phones.) The words that
> are modified by those rules will sound differently in connected speech
> than in citation form (canonical form or isolation form).

Types of connected speech principles
Coalescence
Lenition
Elision   [vibes that sounding like vibesat]
Assimilation
Simplification
Liaison
Juncture

[Connected speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_speech#:%7E:text=In%20linguistics%2C%20connected%20speech%20or,%2C%20syllables%2C%20phonemes%20or%20phones.)

What one sees written in sentences is not always how those sentences would actually be spoken. Also, this happens in all varieties of English.

Comment: Thanks. I can't open Wikipedia till someone teaches me to climb over GFW

Comment: @Tim I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: it's related to working around human right violation

Comment: @Tim Please don't play games like that. It's obfuscatory and confusing.

Comment: Presumably he means the Great Firewall of China. They famously block Wikipedia.

Comment: @OmarandLorraine Ah, right. Thanks. Sorry, Tim. Personally, I have always like Chinese names in English. I don't know why but in the last 20 years, Chinese speakers all Anglicize their names...